# Upload a blob using p_parm_values in PL/SQL apex_web_service.make_rest_request

Tags: oracle, plsql, alfresco

I am trying to use Apex (cloud) to run a PL/SQL script that fetches a BLOB object from a table and sends it via a POST API call to an Alfresco Server.

If I were using Postman/Insomnia for the API call, I would do the following:

1. Set the Content-Type to be "multipart/form-data"
2. Add a key in the body called "filedata"
3. For its value, I would select a file from the local filesystem

[image]

This I would send as a POST request with basic authentication.

I am having trouble replicating this using PL/SQL with the APEX_WEB_SERVICE module.
Below is the code that I am trying:

```
DECLARE
    f_attachment BLOB;
    f_response CLOB;
    v_login VARCHAR2(100);
    v_password VARCHAR2(100);
    l_offset     INT := 1;
    p_clob CLOB;
BEGIN
    v_login := '***';
    v_password := '***';
    
    
    
    SELECT PDF INTO f_attachment FROM VIPUL_TEST WHERE ID=2;
    
    
    apex_web_service.g_request_headers.delete;
    apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).name := 'Content-Type';
    apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).value := 'multipart/form-data';
    
    f_response := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(p_url => 'https://systest.eisenvault.net/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/nodes/2b9d7fc9-a12e-4e0b-89b2-e556ddfd2778/children',  
                                                     p_http_method => 'POST',
                                                     p_username => v_login,
                                                     p_password => v_password,
                                                     p_parm_name => apex_util.string_to_table('filedata'),
                                                     p_parm_value => apex_util.string_to_table(apex_web_service.blob2clobbase64(f_attachment))

    );
    
    

    -- Print out the CLOB fetched from Database
    p_clob := apex_web_service.blob2clobbase64(f_attachment);

    dbms_output.put_line('Print CLOB');    
    loop  
        exit when l_offset > dbms_lob.getlength(p_clob);  
        dbms_output.put_line( dbms_lob.substr( p_clob, 255, l_offset ) );  
        l_offset := l_offset + 255;  
    end loop; 
    -- Finish Printing
END;
```

I am getting the below error:

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at line 21
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721


1. DECLARE
2.  f_attachment BLOB;
3.  f_response CLOB;
4.  v_login VARCHAR2(100);
```

It seems that the clob can't be passed as a value in p_parm_value. Can you suggest a way to make this work? Is there a way to turn a Blob or a Clob into a string? I am reluctant to convert this into a varchar type, because that has an upper limit of 32kb (right?), whereas these attachments can be multiple gigabytes in size.

Answer (score 0):

We solved this ourselves. Below is the code that worked.

```
DECLARE
    l_clob clob;    
    l_json clob;
    lb_blob blob;
    l_body clob;
    lv_filename      VARCHAR2(20)  := 'my_file.pdf';
    lm_multipart     apex_web_service.t_multipart_parts;

BEGIN
    SELECT PDF
      INTO lb_blob
      FROM VIPUL_TEST WHERE ID = 3;

  apex_web_service.APPEND_TO_MULTIPART (
                p_multipart    => lm_multipart,
                p_name         => 'filedata',
                p_filename     => lv_filename,
                p_content_type => 'application/octet-stream',
                p_body_blob    => lb_blob );


 l_clob := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(
              p_url => 'https://systest.eisenvault.net/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/nodes/2b9d7fc9-a12e-4e0b-89b2-e556ddfd2778/children',
              p_username => '***',
              p_password => '***',
              p_http_method => 'POST',
              p_body_blob => apex_web_service.generate_request_body(lm_multipart));
              

    dbms_output.put_line(to_char(l_clob));
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try send it via following parameter of APEX_WEB_SERVICE.MAKE_REST_REQUEST function:

```
p_body_blob IN BLOB default empty_blob()
```